# Switch between projects in Python

Tags: python

I would like to have all of my Python projects in subfolders under a main 'pydev' folder. When I launch Python, I'm in that 'pydev' top level folder.

```
\pydev\proj_1
\pydev\proj_2
etc
```

I'd like to issue a single command to switch to the project folder in question. The best I've found is

```
import os
os.chdir('proj_1')
```

Is there a better way to switch to a project's folder? Or is there a better way to manage multiple Python projects?

Comment: It's not a good approach, if you change your working directory at run time you may end up in error

Comment: when you say "switch", do you mean that all `import`s after the "switch" should find files from the new project?

Comment: This is an XY problem. *What is the ultimate goal you intend to achieve by doing that?*

Comment: Instead, `NEW_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, r'proj_1')` then here after use `NEW_DIR` to point to your proj location

Comment: as a side note, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: And this is what modules are for.

Comment: you might be looking for `workon` command from [`virtualenvwrapper`](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using eclipse "working sets" since you are using PyDev. You can create a project and assign one or more projects to a working set. You can switch between working sets with one click.